# psycopg2 returns single row in output

Tags: python, postgresql

```
import psycopg2
from contextlib import closing
import inspect

db = psycopg2.connect(<credentials>)

query = "SELCT * FROM \
<tablename> \
LIMIT 100;"

with closing(db.cursor()) as cur:
    cur.execute(query)
    results = cur.fetchall()
    print(len(results))

db.close()
```

With the above simple query and code, I am trying to read results from a SELECT query but the results object always have a single record instead of all. Query is working fine in pgadmin query tool, how do I fix this? Thanks in advance for any suggestions here.

Edit #1 (for snakecharmerb): While checking / printing results, I am always getting a single row correctly giving the query results.

Edit #2 (for Expurple): Thanks for the suggestion, will try that. I believe that is not affecting the overall query result.

Comment: For me, the code always prints the number of rows retrieved by the query.  Are you sure you are connected to the correct database and schema?  If you print `results` itself, what do you get?

Comment: A minor suggestion: it's easier to use a multiline string literal (`"""your query here"""`) than to add a backslash at the end of each line. `psycopg2` doesn't mind multiline queries

Comment: Are you sure that you are interpreting the result correctly?  The expected response would be a _list_ of _tuples_, something like `[(1, 'a'), (2, 'b'), (3, 'c'), ...]`.  Each tuple in the list is a row from the query result.